# Javascript - Index Each Element in an Array/List

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
> var lst = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
> someFunc(lst);
[('red', 0), ('blue', 1), ('yellow', 2)]
```

Is there any way to do this in Javascript/JQuery? I know that I can simply just make a for loop and convert each of the original list's element to what I want, but I was wondering if there was a built in way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: UM, you want objects? nested arrays? That output does not make sense

Comment: You mean `lst.map(function(v, i) { return { value: v, index: i } } )`?

Comment: Something that puts the index to each element, could be objects.

Comment: Why by the way? lst[0] is red, lst[1] is blue. lst.indexOf("yellow") is 2

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return for each item an array with the value and the index.

```js
var lst = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
    array = lst.map(function (a, i) { return [a, i]; });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yep! Except the comma should be a semi-colon, right?

Comment: No, Nina's declaring two variables, its shorthand for writing `var lst ...; var array ...;`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `map()` function that is providing you both the value and and index of each item in the array:

```
lst.map(function(v, i) { return { value: v, index: i }; } );
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

With map method in ES6 :

```
var lst = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
var array = lst.map((item, index) => [item, index])
console.log(array); // [ [ 'red', 0 ], [ 'blue', 1 ], [ 'yellow', 2 ] ]
```